# Removing number of dots with grep using regular expression

Tags: linux, bash

How can I remove lines that contain more than 5 "." or less than 5 dots (simply put: 5 dots per line?
How can I write a regex that will detect it in bash using grep?

INPUT:

```
yGEtfWYBCBKtvxTbHxMK,126.221.42.321.0.147.30,10,Bad stuff is happening,http://mystuff.com/file.json
yGEtfWYBCBKtvxTbHxwK,126.221.42.21,10,Bad stuff is happening,http://mystuff.com/file.json
```

EXPECTED OUTPUT:

```
yGEtfWYBCBKtvxTbHxwK,176.221.42.21,10,Bad stuff is happening,http://mystuff.com/file.json
```

Tried:

```
grep -P '[.]{5}' stuff.txt
grep -P '[\.]{5}' stuff.txt
grep -P '([\.]{5})' stuff.txt
grep -P '\.{5}' stuff.txt
grep -E '([\.]{5}' stuff.txt
```

Comment: Your attempts all look for five adjacent matches. The `[\.]{5}` ones look for five adjacent characters which are either backslash or dot, i.e. `.\.\.` , `\....`,etc. The last one lacks a closing parenthesis, so that's a regex syntax error.

Comment: Closest one was `\.{5}`, but yeah that only matches consecutive characters and missed representing the characters that were found between the dots

Comment: If your goal is to filter out invalid lines it'd be smarter to look for bad IP addresses, bad URLs, etc., as separate items. Counting the number of dots in an entire line is going to get you in trouble. What if the "Bad stuff is happening" message contains a dot? It's best to be as specific as possible to avoid unwanted side effects.

Comment: URL is always the same, therefore counting dots seems to be the very solid idea as I know expected (always) number of dot characters. I do not control however the inserted IP address and I do not have control on the source that gives me this data. It is not much, 10k IP addresses, hence bash as the development of the basic script took me 10 minutes. Thank you for the comments.

Answer (score 2):

You can display only the lines that contain exactly 5 dots as follow :

```
grep '^[^.]*\.[^.]*\.[^.]*\.[^.]*\.[^.]*\.[^.]*$' stuff.txt
```

or if you want to factor it :

```
grep -E '^([^.]*\.){5}[^.]*$' stuff.txt
```

Using `-E`RE in this second one is helpful to avoid having to escape the `\(\)` and `\{\}`, in the first one `grep`'s default BRE regex flavour is sufficient.

`^` and `$` are anchors representing respectively the start and end of the line that make sure we match the whole line and not just a part of it that contains 5 dots.

`[^.]` is a negated character class that will match anything but a dot.
They are quantified with `*` so that any number of non-dot characters can happen between each dot (you might want to change that to `+` if consecutive dots shouldn't be matched).

`\.` matches a literal dot (rather than any character, which the meta-character `.` outside of a character class would).

Answer (score 0):

To detect specifically the bad IP address

Can you be certain that the IP address is always surrounded by commas and does not contain spaces - i.e. is never the first or last field?

Then, you might get away with:

```
grep -E ',\w+((\.\w+){2,3}|(\.\w+){5,}),'
```

If not, it is quite difficult to distinguish between a broken IP form with spaces and an ordinary sentence, so you might have to specify the column.

Comment: It is kind of what I am attempting to do. First stage parsing: grep -P '(?!(10\.|172\.(1[6-9]|2\d|3[01])\.|192\.168\.).*)(?!255\.255\.255\.255)(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[1]\d\d|[1-9]\d|[1-9])(\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[1]\d\d|[1-9]\d|\d)){3}'  , and later the |sort -u -nk2 -t"," | grep -E '^([^.]*\.){6}[^.]*$', but to make it very robust I would have to cover all exceptions possible or use different language for that. For the basic automation it does the job, and I report exceptions by sending email / creating Jira ticket.

Answer (score -1):

Using Perl one-liner to print only if number of "." exceeds 5

```
> cat five_dots.txt
yGEtfWYBCBKtvxTbHxMK,126.221.42.321.0.147.30,10,Bad stuff is happening,http://mystuff.com/file.json
yGEtfWYBCBKtvxTbHxwK,126.221.42.21,10,Bad stuff is happening,http://mystuff.com/file.json
> perl -ne '{ while(/\./g){$count++} print if $count > 5; $count=0 } ' five_dots.txt
yGEtfWYBCBKtvxTbHxMK,126.221.42.321.0.147.30,10,Bad stuff is happening,http://mystuff.com/file.json
>
```